# New firefox window is not getting recognized by the selenium web driver...but the same piece of code works fine with IE

Tags: selenium-webdriver

New firefox window is not getting recognized by the selenium web driver...but the same piece of code works fine with IE

```
int size= getDriver().getWindowHandles().size();
System.out.println("Size====>"+size);System.out.println("Windows=====>"+getDriver().getWindowHandles());
Thread.sleep(3000);
String handle2 = (String)getDriver().getWindowHandles().toArray()[1];
getDriver().switchTo().window(handle2);
System.out.println(getDriver().getTitle());
```

size returned in case of FF is 1.

Firefox version 29 and IE 9

Selenium -40

Answer (score 0):

Try to downgrade to Firefox 28 as the newest Selenium doesn't support Firefox 29.

You can find the Selenium change log here:
http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/rb/CHANGES

Comment: Hi,I was using FF 28 before, when it did not work I upgraded it to the lates.